# static_cast in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, compilation, static-cast

I know that static casts are handled at compile time, but what about a static cast in the conditional of a for loop? Will the cast be made with each iteration, or only once during compilation? I'm concerned about the cost of this implementation. I know that the compiler will cast the type automatically, I'm just trying to remove the warning. For example:

```
double limit = 10.0;

for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(limit); i++)
{
   ...
}
```

The warning is: "conversion from 'double' to 'int' may alter its value."

Comment: `I'm just trying to remove the warning`  what warning?

Comment: What should be special with this?!? Tt's just treated like in any other place. And no, the cast will be applied once.

Comment: I think you vastly underestimate your compiler's optimisation capabilities...

Comment: Your question is based on the incorrect assumption _"static casts are handled at compile time"_.  Static casts are handled at **run time**, unless your compiler can make a compile-time optimization.

Comment: Why are static_casts handled run time? Or when?

Comment: @Zsolt Because they may take a run-time value of one type and cast it to a value of another type. If the input is determined at runtime, how could it be handled at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `double` and an `int` are not the same thing, they usually require different registers and the conversion is generally not free. If the compiler is able to prove that `limit` is not changed inside the loop it can reduce the conversion to being done once at the beginning of the loop. If the compiler can prove that `limit` equals `10.0` then the static cast may just be replaced by a `10` at compile time.

Comment: Thank you! The variables used in my example are arbitrary, and do not reflect the user-defined types I'm really working with.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your "`...`" code.

---

For this code, `limit` is known at compile-time.

Your compiler can conclude that it can perform the `static_cast` **once at compile time**.  Your <strike>compiler</strike> *colleagues* may also wonder why you didn't make `limit` *`const`*.  Or why it's a `double` to begin with.

```
double limit = 10.0;

for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(limit); i++)
{
   std::cout << i;
}
```

---

For this code, `limit` is not known at compile time.

Your compiler must perform the `static_cast` **each loop at run time**.  Your compiler may also wonder why you didn't make `limit` *`const`*.

```
double limit = 10.0;

for(int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(limit); i++)
{
   std::cin >> limit;
}
```

Comment: It might not be constant in the real code, although I don't know how the compiler will "wonder"?

Comment: @NeilKirk I was perhaps being too anthropomorphic.  You are correct that it is not the compiler's function to _wonder things_.  People wonder things.